PrimeNG dropdown filtering multilanguage options
We're using Angular v16 with PrimeNG 16 and NGX-Translate v15. Translating is working fine, however, filtering is problematic. The label usually comes in codetable code for example "some.resource.key".
Filtering is looking for "some.resource.key" and not "some.resource.key" | translate
<p-dropdown
  [options]="options"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
  [filter]="true"
  [showClear]="true"
>
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
      {{ item.label | translate }}
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
      {{ item.label | translate }}
  </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>


Is there any way how to solve this? I already tried to translate manually and set the options with the already translated labels, but it's too much boilerplate and a lot of cases to handle in each component. I am looking for a better solution.
EDIT
I am aiming to resource keys: "codetable.item1", "codetable.item2"
Translated to EN: "codetable.item1": "sweet"
Translated to FR: "codetable.item1": "doux".
The resource keys and translated labels have no common letters.
Stackblitz demo,
Filtering problem screenshot
Thank you!

We need to create a custom directive which will handle this scenario, where we translate the fields and store in a property translatedLabel
Working example and stackblitz below!
FULL CODE
translate dropdown directive
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Dropdown } from 'primeng/dropdown';
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[translateDropdown]',
})
export class TranslateDropdownDirective {
  @Input() newProp = 'translatedLabel';
  @Input() sourceProp = 'label';

  constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private pDropdown: Dropdown
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    merge(
      this.translate.onTranslationChange,
      this.translate.onDefaultLangChange,
      this.translate.onLangChange
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.setTranslatedValues();
    });
    this.setTranslatedValues();
  }

  setTranslatedValues() {
    this.pDropdown.options.forEach((item: any) => {
      item[this.newProp] = item?.[this.sourceProp]
        ? this.translate.instant(item[this.sourceProp])
        : item?.[this.sourceProp];
    });
    this.pDropdown.options = [...this.pDropdown.options];
  }
}

html
<div>
  <h2>{{ 'HOME.TITLE' | translate }}</h2>
  <label>
    {{ home | translate }}
    <select
      #langSelect
      [(ngModel)]="selectedLang"
      (ngModelChange)="setLanguage()"
    >
      <option
        *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()"
        [value]="lang"
        [selected]="lang === translate.currentLang"
      >
        {{ lang }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
  <p-dropdown
    [options]="tastes"
    translateDropdown
    [(ngModel)]="selectedTaste"
    [showClear]="true"
    [filter]="true"
    optionLabel="translatedLabel"
    filterBy="translatedLabel"
    placeholder="Select a Taste"
  >
  </p-dropdown>
</div>

TS
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

interface Taste {
  id: number;
  label: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown-basic-demo',
  templateUrl: './dropdown-basic-demo.html',
})
export class DropdownBasicDemo implements OnInit {
  selectedLang = 'en';
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(['en', 'fr']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

    const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');
  }
  tastes: Taste[] | undefined;

  selectedTaste: undefined;
  home = 'HOME.SELECT';

  setLanguage() {
    this.translate.use(this.selectedLang);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tastes = [
      { id: 1, label: 'HOME.DROPDOWN.ITEM1' },
      { id: 2, label: 'HOME.DROPDOWN.ITEM2' },
    ];
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you for your help, but this is not very good example as resource keys and translated results are similar: "ROME" and "NEW", so the result will be almost everytime similar.
I am aiming to resource keys like: "codetable.item1", "codetable.item2"
and translated to EN:
"codetable.item1": "sweet"
translated to FR:
"codetable.item1": "doux"
So resource key, EN translated key and FR translated key have nothing in common.

@Marek please replicate the issue in the stackblitz and share back, why can't ROME work but not item1???? replace . with something else!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/9stsj2-nhf1uq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fdropdown-basic-demo.html

@Marek updated my answer, the logic is still the same, I just changed how the dropdown change will set the language using ngModel do check once!

Thanks for updated stackblitz. Filtering, however, still does not work as expected:
screenshot
